# Make API call from message filter extension on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sms, ios-extensions

I'm working on a message filter extension for iOS and I am kind of stuck. I would like to make an API call inside the extension class that is responsible with filtering the received messages but so far it's not working. I can use exactly the same code inside the ViewController class and everything is working fine.
So my question is: is it possible to make an API call from a message filter extension? (if it is, is there some kind of special setup that I am missing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_mms_message_filtering) it is not possible to make any network calls inside the extension, the system should handle it and communicate with server associated with your app for you

> For privacy reasons, the system handles all communication with your associated server; your Message Filter app extension can't access the network directly.
>
> Also for privacy reasons, your app extension can't write data to containers shared with the containing app.

So to make the call to your server you should call [`deferQueryRequestToNetwork(completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/ilmessagefilterextensioncontext/2880240-deferqueryrequesttonetwork) on the `ILMessageFilterExtensionContext` instance

> If your app extension can't make this determination by itself, it tells Messages to send the information about the message to a server associated with your app. Your server examines the message information and sends a response to Messages, which passes the response to your app extension.